# Installing solc0.8.9 for solidity

Tags: mocha.js, solidity, web3js, ganache

I am taking a  Solidity course on Udemy.
In the lesson, I had to install solc0.8.9.
The lesson guide

1. `mkdir inbox-updated`
2. `cd inbox-updated`
3. `npm init _y`
4. `npm install solc@0.8.9 web3 mocha ganache-cli@truffle/hdwallet-provider`

at step 4, after I put the line on git Bash, github asks me to authorize to 'Git Credential Manager'. Then after authorized I get some error message.

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/truffle/hdwallet-provider.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Can someone help me to figure out.

```
install solc0.8.9 web3 mocha ganache-cli@truffle/hdwallet-provider
```

2023/01/11 It's solved by myself.

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from git, and the npm error is returning git's error. The "Permission denied" implies you do not have an ssh key set up in git bash. git/github have documentation here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key

Comment: Thank you for ansering my question. I forget to update my question that actualy I found what was wrong was just I forgot to put space between ganache-cli and @truffle.